# Why $e^{-x^2}$ is Lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Why $x\longmapsto e^{-x^2}$ is Lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb R$ ? How to justify it rigorously ?

I know that on compact, if it's Riemann integrable, then it's also Lebesgue, but how does it work over $\mathbb R$ ? Because I know that Riemann integrable doesn't implies Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Because $$e^{-x^2}\leqslant\frac1{1+x^2}$$

Comment: @Did: Ok, but why $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ Lebesgue integrable ? How can I show it rigorously ?

Comment: Because it has antiderivative $\arctan$.

Comment: @user330587 any non-negative Riemann integrable function is also Lebesgue integrable

Comment: @user330587 to prove this rigorously, it suffices to use the monotone convergence theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \geq 0$ is Riemann integrable over $\Bbb R$, then it is also Lebesgue integrable.

To see this, it suffices to use the monotone convergence theorem.  Define
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) & -n \leq x \leq n\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $f_n \to f$ pointwise and for all $x \in \Bbb R$, $n \geq m \implies f_n(x) \geq f_m(x)$. By the monotone convergence theorem, we may conclude that
$$
\int f\,d\mu = \int  \lim_{n \to \infty } f_n \,d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n \, d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx
$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that one has:
$$e^{-x^2}=o_{x\to\pm\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right).$$
Therefore, since $2>1$, $\displaystyle x\mapsto\frac{1}{x^2}$ is Lebesgue-integrable over $]-\infty,-1[\cup]1,+\infty[$ and so is $x\mapsto e^{-x^2}$. Finally, notice that $x\mapsto e^{-x^2}$ is continuous over $[-1,1]$ which is compact so that $x\mapsto e^{-x^2}$ is Lebesgue-integrable over $[-1,1]$.

Comment: The question is for all of $\Bbb{R}.$

Comment: @Chickenmancer And this is precisely what I have shown since it is Lebesgue-integrable over $]\infty,-1[\cup]1,+\infty[$ and $[-1,1]$ whose union is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why is $\frac{1}{x^2}$ lebesgue integrable over $]-\infty ,-1[\cup]1,+\infty [$ ?

Comment: @user330587 $\int_1^{\infty} \frac 1{x^2} dx$ is finite, as is $\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac 1{x^2} dx$